# Count values of a Multi-Valued attribute for each Row in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following schema:

Contact:

```
ID|    NAME   |Contact
----------------------
1 |     A     |1234,4567
-----------------------
2 |     B     |2345,5678,9012
```

Here, as you can see `Contact` is a `Multivalued field` and A person can have as many as contact numbers.

Now, I want to count the number of contacts for each person.
How can I do that?

Note: I don't want to normalize this table.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Fix your data structure!  You should have a junction tables and not store numeric ids in a delimited *string*.

Comment: Why would you not want proper data structure?

Comment: It's not a college level assignment, so I'm not the one who defined schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't advise doing this, this is how you would do it:

```
SELECT ID, (LENGTH(Contact) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Contact,",","")) + 1) AS NumberOfContacts    
FROM MyTable
```

The output will look like this:

```
ID| NumberOfContacts
1 | 2
2 | 3
```

The difference in length after the replace will tell you how many commas were in the string, then you would need to add 1 to include the last number. You should really structure the data properly, but if that is out of the question then you will need to work with something like this